# Prove that the open ball $B(0,1) \in \mathbb{C}$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Using the theorem, An open set $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ is connected iff for any two points $a,b$ in $G$ there is a polygon from $a$ to $b$ lying entirely in $G$.

I know an open ball is indeed an open set. I'm having trouble formulating the proof that if I have two points $a$ and $b$. I can form a polygon from $0$ to $a$ and another polygon from $0$ to $b$. Since both polygons share an endpoint, $0$, then they form one polygon.

How would I go about starting this proof?

Comment: Do you mean "path" when you say "polygon"?

Comment: My text defines "A polygon from $a$ to $b$ is a set $P = \cup_{k=1}^n[z_k, w_k]$ where $z_1 = a$, $w_n = b$ and $w_k = z_{k+1}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ or $P = [a, z_2, ..., z_n, b]$

Comment: I still think it's easier to work with paths than polygons. It also generalises better to non-open sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply join $a$ and $b$ with a segment?

Let $a,b\in B(0,1)$ the $t\to ta+(1-t)b$ for $t\in [0,1]$ is a parametrization of the segment that joins $a$ and $b$. All the points along this segment are inside $B(0,1)$ because for all $t\in [0,1]$,
$$|ta+(1-t)b|\leq  t|a|+(1-t)|b|< t\cdot 1+(1-t)\cdot 1=1.$$

Comment: @Zed1 Any further doubt?

Comment: Not at all. I knew that there was a way to connect the two points without going through the centre, but I wasn't sure how to go about it. Thank you.